# Insert space after certain character into javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a form and I'd like to mask the input of the phone numbers. The plugins what I found aren't okay for me since the area code could be 1 or 2 character long.
What I'd like to do is the following: 
when the user types his number after the first two character the script inserts a space on keyup, then after the next three and later after every fourth character. 
So when someone types 44444444444 then in the textbox appears 44 44 444 4444. 
I must check the second group as well, and when someone types there for example 1, the the number must look like: 44 1 444 4444

Is any solution to do that?

Comment: "I must check the second group as well, and when someone types there for example 1, the the number must look like: 44 1 444 4444", is that the case only for 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ffwAA/4/

Which applies this function to the string to get the desired formatting:

```
function formatCode(str){
    var result = str;

    str = str.replace(/\D+/g, "");
    var m = str.match(/^(\d\d)(?:([2-90]\d|1)(?:(\d\d\d)(\d+)?)?)?$/);

    if(m){
        result = m[1] + " ";
        if(m[2]) result += m[2] + " ";
        if(m[3]) result += m[3] + " ";

        if(m[4]){
            result += m[4].split(/(\d{4})/).join(" ");
            result = result.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And using this jQuery to set it up:

```
function update(obj){
    var val = obj.value;
    var got = formatCode(val);

    if(got != val)
        obj.value = got;
}

var timer;
var prev_val = "";

$('#code').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);

    // when adding numbers at the end of input, update at once
    // don't want to update when editing in the middle of the string or removing parts of it
    // because it would move the carret location to the end of input, and make it unusable
    if(this.value.indexOf(prev_val) == 0){
        update(this);
        prev_val = this.value;
        return;
    }

    prev_val = this.value;

    // in other cases update 1 second after the changes are done
    timer = setTimeout(update, 1000, this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the maskedInput plugin?

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

I think it can solve your problem.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: yes, I tried but the problem is the area code. With this plugin I can mask the area code as two or one character. :s