# Is there a way to format MySQL celldata via the column type/attributes?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am capturing 2 sets of data in 2 mysql columns:

```
Name       |  Number
-----------------------
Anonymous  |  123456789
anonymous  |  0123 456 789
```

I want to standardise the format of each column to be 1) capitalised and 2) number formated with a particular pattern:

```
Name       |  Number
-----------------------
Anonymous  |  0123 456 789
Anonymous  |  0123 456 789
```

Is there a way I can do this via setting a type/attribute in the mysql database itself (in the same way zerofill adds zeros in an INT(X) type), or do I need to format the data before entry to the database? If the latter, how would I do this with Javascript/Jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Better to do all those kind of stuffs in js/ajax.

Comment: You need to manage it while storing or retriving data from database.

Comment: What if someone have js deactived in his browser? You're client side controls won't work! You've to consider this! Server side control of this is better

Comment: Dont u think its a overhead to do in queries ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may fetch the data in the correct format with some useful [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(t.name, 2))),
    REPLACE(FORMAT(t.number, 0), ',', ' ')
FROM table t
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using PHP/JS to convert to Title case.

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

However you can read this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191605/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-mysql-data-into-title-case) to learn how to convert to Title case using MySQL.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579584/insert-space-after-certain-character-into-javascript-string) to learn how to add spaces between a string using Javascript.